# For every club $C$ there is a club $D\subset C:\ |C\setminus D|=\kappa$ and thus $|club_{\kappa}|>\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

I have two questions, but they seem to be closely related to each other.

The first one is to show that for every club $C$ in an uncountable, regular cardinal $\kappa$, there is a club $D\subset C:\ |C\setminus D|=\kappa$. My first thought was to use transfinite induction over all the elements of $C$ and in each step pick the the two smallest ones, $x_{\alpha},y_{\alpha}$, not previouly chosen. But in this way I have no guarantee that $\{x_{\alpha}: \alpha<\kappa\}$ will be closed (I think).

EDIT: Can I salvage this construction by taking $\sup$ of previously chosen $x_{\alpha}$'s at limit steps?

The second question is to prove $|club_{\kappa}|>\kappa$. What I thought of, was to choose $\kappa$-many different clubs (I can always do that using the previous part, i.e. $C_{\alpha}=C\cup\{y_{\alpha}\}$ should form $\kappa$ different closed and unbounded sets). Then, knowing there is always a club inside of them, we could form $2^{\kappa}$ different sums from $C_{\alpha}$ and $D_{\alpha}\subset C_{\alpha}$. But here, on the other hand, I'm not certain if an arbitrary sum of clubs would also be a club.

Hence, I don't know how to prove either of the assertions. Please, help.

Comment: What do you call a "club" ?

Comment: A set which is closed (limit of every sequence is also in the set) and unbounded.

Comment: One more question, pardon me: On which topological space ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: The topological space is $ \kappa $ equipped with the order topology.

Comment: @Berrick Caleb Fillmore Thanks, it becomes clearer...

Comment: If $ (x_{\alpha})_{\alpha < \kappa} $ is an order-preserving enumeration of $ C $, then would the set of all $ x_{\beta} $, where $ \beta $ is the ordinal sum of a limit ordinal $ \gamma < \kappa $ and an even finite ordinal $ n $, work?

Comment: So basically you mean $C\cap Lim=D$? Then the set of all non limit ordinals has $\kappa$ many elements as otherwise it would be bounded, which is obviously false. I guess it works then.

Comment: Letting $ D \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} C \cap \mathbf{LimOrd} $ doesn’t seem right as $ C $ could consist only of limit ordinals. Don’t forget that you want $ |C \setminus D| = \kappa $.

Comment: Do you know the proof that the set of limit points of some set $A$ in a topological space is closed? It's just that.

Comment: All right, but how does the complement have $\kappa$ many elements then?

Comment: You could take the elements of $ C $ whose **index via the enumeration** is a limit ordinal. In this manner, you’ll be leaving behind some elements to form $ C \setminus D $.

Comment: Ok, thank you, you're right. And what about the second part, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Club is a club is a club. :-)

Comment: I don’t know what $ \operatorname{club}_{\kappa} $ means. Perhaps we could call upon @AsafKaragila to display his formidable technical prowess?

Comment: It's the set of all clubs on $\kappa$. And one morw thing: is my modified construction with taking limit points at limit steps is correct?

Comment: Given any $\kappa$ clubs, take a diagonal intersection and proceed with the usual diagonal argument...

Comment: You can also show directly, take any subset $A$ of $\{\delta+5\mid\delta<\kappa\text{ is a limit ordinal}\}$ and show that $\kappa\setminus A$ is a club.

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is club in $\kappa,$ with regular uncountable $k,$ let $$D=\{x\in C: x=\sup (x\cap C)\}.$$ Then (i).$|C$ \ $D|=\kappa.$ (ii). $D$ is club in $\kappa .$

(i): For  $y\in C$  let $f(y)=\min (C$ \ $(y+1))$. Then $f$ is $1$-to-$1$ and $f(y)\in C$ \ $D.$

(ii): For $z\in \kappa,$ let $z<y_0\in C.$  For $n\in \omega$ let $y_{n+1}=\min (C$ \ $(y_n+1)).$ Then $z<x=\sup_{n\in \omega}y_n<\kappa$ because $cf(k)>\omega$.  So $z<x\in D$. So  $D$ is unbounded in $\kappa.$

A topological exercise: $D$ is the set of accumulation points of a subset ( $C$)  of a $T_1$ space so $D$ is closed.