# Showing that $ |\operatorname{club}_\kappa| > \kappa $

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Show that $ |\operatorname{club}_\kappa| > \kappa $

Worded differently:

> Show that there are more than $ \kappa $ closed and unbounded subsets of $\kappa$

I think this might be some sort of standard diagonal argument, however, I have no idea where to begin

I would appreciate some help

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917603/for-every-club-c-there-is-a-club-d-subset-c-c-setminus-d-kappa-and-thus

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple construction. Let $L$ be the set of all limit points of $\kappa$. It’s a club of size $\kappa$. For each $X\subseteq L$, take
$$C=\{\alpha+1\mid\alpha \in X\}\cup L\;;$$ this is again a club.

Comment: That's very clever. Is this just cleverness or could you please elaborate on how you came up with it?

Comment: I dont really think its that clever, but thank you. Sorry but it just came to me.

Comment: @Jytug: One of the simplest ways to get more than $\kappa$ sets is to get $2^\kappa$ sets. A natural place to look for $2^\kappa$ sets is the power set of some set of cardinality $\kappa$. The trick is finding an appropriate set of cardinality $\kappa$ and a way to use its subsets; that’s where Rene’s ingenuity came into play.

Comment: You could also just take $X\subseteq\kappa\setminus L$ and consider $L\cup X$, which is a bit simpler.